# excel vba scan col z to col a, delete if col header doesn't match set of values delete column

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns

I'm trying to scan Columns Z to A, if the column header (in row 2) doesn't match a set list of values then delete the column or range ("Z2:Z"& last_row, etc etc).

here is my code so far ( the column section I found online but it's not working)

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

WBPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")

'scan for the line to delete row 2 , row 3, row 4 depending
For i = 6 To 2 Step -1
    If Range("A" & i) = "" Then
        Rows(i).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                End If
                    Next i

'scan columns for matching names
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim j As Long
    Dim delRange As Range

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        '~~> Loop through relevant columns
        For j = 26 To 1 Step -1
            '~~> Check if the value is equal to YY
            If Worksheets(ws).Cells(2, j).Value <> "Name" Or "F/N" Or "Ref Des" Or "Component Location" Or "Qty" Then
                Columns(i).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlLeft
            End If
        Next j
    End With
```

Failing on this line with type 13 mismatch

```
If Worksheets(ws).Cells(2, j).Value <> "Name" Or "F/N" Or "Ref Des" Or "Component Location" Or "Qty" Then
```

I think that my code for the rows is much cleaner, is there a similar method for columns, or a better method to scan and kill the columns?

Comment: ***OR*** does not work that way.

Comment: You just need `If .Cells(2, j).Value <> "Name" Or .Cells(2, j).Value <> "F/N" etc`. `ws` is already defined as a sheet variable. But I agree with BigBen about SC.

Comment: `Select Case` might be a cleaner option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to use the **OR** statement is wrong.

**OR** -  Signifies that only one condition must be met.

**AND** - Signifies that both conditions are required.

Give it a try to this...

```
 '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        '~~> Loop through relevant columns
        For j = 26 To 1 Step -1
            '~~> Check if the value is equal to YY
            If .Cells(2, j) <> "Name" And .Cells(2, j) <> "F/N" And .Cells(2, j) <> "Ref Des" And .Cells(2, j) <> "Component Location" And .Cells(2, j) <> "Qty" Then
                Columns(j).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlLeft
            End If
        Next j
    End With
```

Comment: Theres roughly 25 columns, I only want to keep' "Name" "F/N" "Ref Des" "Component Location" "Qty" ' are the columns I'd like to keep, I wasn't sure of how to have the loop scan for any of these values and delete the columns that aren't on that list. sorry if that wasn't clear